# проблема с отладкой MIPS в qemu (gdbserver+radare2)

Tags: отладка, gdb, mips, radare2

Попробую структурировать все по порядку, чтобы всем было понятно, в чем же у меня проблема.

Имеем:

- KVM qemu-system-mips.
  Полностью эмулируем систему командой:

```
qemu-system-mips -M malta -kernel 'vmlinux-2.6.32-5-4kc-malta' -hda xm.img -append "root=/dev/sda console=tty0 init=/init" -net nic,macaddr=00:16:3e:00:00:01 -net tap
```

> QEMU emulator version 2.8.0(Debian 1:2.8+dfsg-3) Copyright (c)
> 2003-2016 Fabrice Bellard and the QEMU Project developers

- Образ эмулируемой системы D-link 632, скачанной с официального сайта.

> 0             0x0             uImage header, header size: 64 bytes,
> header CRC: 0x83F3D3D4, created: 2016-01-14 14:02:07, image size:
> 1290693 bytes, Data Address: 0x80002000, Entry Point: 0x802AF3F0, data
> CRC: 0x606A98CE, OS: Linux, CPU: MIPS, image type: OS Kernel Image,
> compression type: lzma, image name: "DIR_632"

- Подопытный демон resident PID=413

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Находим gdbserver.mipsbe вот здесь  https://github.com/rapid7/embedded-tools/tree/master/binaries/gdbserver
- Переносим на нашу виртуальную машину и запускаем с вот такими параметрами:

  `./gdbserver.mipsbe --remote-debug --once --debug 10.0.2.35:6666 --attach 413`
- В ответ получаем

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Ок, запускаем клиент. Пробуем `radare2`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Не попали(
- Пробуем `gdb`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Опять мимо

Кто думает что порт закрыт, вот вывод `nmap`:

```
Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-03-22 10:10 EDT
Nmap scan report for 10.0.2.35
Host is up (0.00087s latency).
Not shown: 996 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
23/tcp   open  telnet
6666/tcp open  irc
8888/tcp open  sun-answerbook
9999/tcp open  abyss
MAC Address: 00:16:3E:00:00:01 (Xensource)
```

В чем проблема, почему не происходит соединения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался. Скачанный gdbserver был собран под архитектуру mips-1, а нужно было mips-32. 
Вопрос решился сборкой gdbserver под необходимую архитектуру.
PS без бубна не обошлось.